# How to use osm.pbf with tilestache?

Tags: openstreetmap, mbtiles, tilestache, raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 moving around in my city. It shows information on a monitor via hdmi. Now it should also display a map of the current position. The Pi has no connection to the internet and will not get one.

I installed tilestache. The example is running fine but if I try to use a mbtiles map from [openmaptiles](https://openmaptiles.org), tilestache is complaining about the pbf format:

```
192.168.0.54 - - [16/Jun/2017 12:00:17] "GET /osm/10/168/398.png HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 209, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 197, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/TileStache/__init__.py", line 413, in __call__
    status_code, headers, content = requestHandler2(self.config, path_info, query_string, script_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/TileStache/__init__.py", line 286, in requestHandler2
    status_code, headers, content = layer.getTileResponse(coord, extension)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/TileStache/Core.py", line 432, in getTileResponse
    tile = self.render(coord, format)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/TileStache/Core.py", line 519, in render
    tile = provider.renderTile(width, height, srs, coord)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/TileStache/MBTiles.py", line 217, in renderTile
    mime_type, content = get_tile(self.tileset, coord)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/TileStache/MBTiles.py", line 159, in get_tile
    mime_type = formats[format]
KeyError: 'pbf'
```

As far as I know, tilestache does not support pbf format in mbtiles. I also have map data in osm.pbf from [Geofabrik](http://download.geofabrik.de/) but I did not found anything about how to use that with tilestache. Can I make tilestache to use osm.pbf?

Comment: Please clarify your question. Right now you are mixing a problem and a general question. geofabrik does not provide mbtiles, pbf is something completely different.

Comment: @bugmenot123 sorry for being imprecisely but the whole topic is new for me. I cannot put too much time into it for the sake of economics so I have to find a fast solution or a totally different one.

Comment: mbtiles containes rendered tiles while PBF contains raw vector data. So in fact you are searching for a tool that creates/renders mbtiles from a PBF file.

Answer (score 1):

[openmaptiles.org](https://openmaptiles.org/) offers mbtiles downloads for the whole planet as well as for individual countries and cities. It is the successor of [osm2vectortiles.org](http://osm2vectortiles.org/).

It contains also a documentation for [generating your own OpenMapTiles](https://openmaptiles.org/docs/generate/generate-openmaptiles/).